# Building gcc plugin for windows on linux

Tags: c++, c, gcc, plugins, compiler-construction

Try to build the following gcc plugin on linux for windows with mingw cross compiler. The plugins are from the built avr compiler also for windows. Adapted the following plugin https://github.com/jcmvbkbc/avr-flash-vtbl.

```
#include <gcc-plugin.h>
#include <cp/cp-tree.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
__declspec(dllexport)
#endif

int plugin_is_GPL_compatible = 1;

void fn(void *gcc_data, void *user_data)
{
    TYPE_ADDR_SPACE (TREE_TYPE (vtbl_type_node)) = 1;
    TYPE_ADDR_SPACE (TREE_TYPE (vtbl_ptr_type_node)) = 1;
}

#ifdef _WIN32
__declspec(dllexport)
#endif    

int plugin_init (struct plugin_name_args *plugin_info,
         struct plugin_gcc_version *version)
{
    register_callback("", PLUGIN_START_UNIT, fn, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Output during compile and linking:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -I/home/andreas/omgwtfbbq/win64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/9.2.0/plugin/include -Wl,--export-all-symbols /home/andreas/
omgwtfbbq/win64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/9.2.0/plugin/cc1plus.exe.a avr-flash-vtbl.c -o avr-flash-vtbl.so -I./
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc28ZVde.o:avr-flash-vtbl.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `cp_global_trees'
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc28ZVde.o:avr-flash-vtbl.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `cp_global_trees'
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc28ZVde.o:avr-flash-vtbl.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `register_callback'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: avr-flash-vtbl.so] Fehler 1
```

The compiler flags are adapted from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins-building.html. Has anybody already faced such a issue?

Comment: Avr compilers with plugin enable, for which the plugin is built:
Win64: https://ig5tf1xybtmow6m2.myfritz.net:49293/nas/filelink.lua?id=13321f5ff7f6c778

Comment: Problem is solved. Changed host compiler from i686-w64-mingw32-g++ to x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ and changed the order of the options. /home/andreas/omgwtfbbq/win64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/9.2.0/plugin/cc1plus.exe.a must go after avr-flash-vtbl.c

Comment: Please post that as the answer to your problem or delete this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Changed host compiler from i686-w64-mingw32-g++ to x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ and changed the order of the options. /home/andreas/omgwtfbbq/win64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/9.2.0/plugin/cc1plus.exe.a must go after avr-flash-vtbl.c.